# when calling the EnableAWSServiceAccess operation: You specified an unrecognized service principal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli, aws-organizations

```
C:\>aws organizations enable-aws-service-access --service-principal cloudformation.amazonaws.com
```

An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the EnableAWSServiceAccess operation: You specified an unrecognized service principal.

```
C:\>aws organizations enable-aws-service-access --service-principal "cloudformation.amazonaws.com"
```

An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the EnableAWSServiceAccess operation: You specified an unrecognized service principal.

```
C:\>aws organizations enable-aws-service-access --service-principal 'cloudformation.amazonaws.com'
```

An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the EnableAWSServiceAccess operation: You provided a value that does not match the required pattern.

Any idea what is wrong?

According to the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/enable-aws-service-access.html)

--service-principal (string)
The service principal name of the AWS service for which you want to enable integration with your organization. This is typically in the form of a URL, such as `service-abbreviation.amazonaws.com` .

I tried with

```
"s3.amazonaws.com"
"ec2.amazonaws.com"
"elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com"
"autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
```

as service-principal. But all gave the same error.

It works in the console though.
AWS Console -> CloudFormation -> StackSets -> Enable trusted access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EnableAWSServiceAccess](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/APIReference/API_EnableAWSServiceAccess.html) is for:

> When you enable integration, you allow the specified service to **create a service-linked role** in all the accounts in your organization. This allows the service to perform operations on your behalf in your organization and its accounts.

The reason it fails, I think, is that **CloudFormation does support service-linked roles**. You can verify that in this tablehttps://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html.

Also it works in console because you are enabling it for `StackSets`, not the `CloudFormation` itself. **CloudFormation does not support trusted access with your organization** as listed in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/services-that-can-integrate.html). Only `AWS CloudFormation Stacksets` supports it.

What's more it only works [though console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/services-that-can-integrate-cloudformation.html):

> You can enable trusted access using either the AWS CloudFormation console or the AWS Organizations console.

You can't do this using CLI or SDK.

Comment: Marcin, Good point on 'cannot do this using CLI'. I marked your answer is correct. But how to explain autoscaling and elasticbeanstalk also fails?

Comment: @Shawn Thanks, they fail in CLI, but work through console?

Comment: @Marcin Can one enable AWS service access using Cloudformation stack, basically is it possible to automate `aws organizations enable-aws-service-access` with some https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-config-organizationconfigrule.html

Comment: @himanshu219 Not sure. I would suggest making new question for that with relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following
`aws organizations enable-aws-service-access --service-principal member.org.stacksets.cloudformation.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Any idea how to enable ec2 or s3 ?